# Generate UPDATE queries from results of SELECT queries

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for an easy way to create UPDATE queries based on the results of certain SELECT queries. The purpose of this is to create a private configuration file that I'm planning to run after I revert my database from a "public" backup.

For example, assuming that I have a table named `setting` with the following table structure:

```
| id_setting | name | value | module |
```

and a query such as:

```
select * from setting where module = 'voip'
```

Based on the results of these queries, I would like to generate INSERT/UPDATE statements that are ultimately stored into my configuration script.

Any idea how to achieve this is a generic way?

PS. I know I can concatenate parts of SQL together but I feel that this approach is to time consuming.

Comment: Which SQL (GUI) client are you using? Most of them have something like that built in.

Answer (score -2):

The closest thing in pgAdmin is the query tool (see http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/query.html).  This would not take your select statements and turn them into queries, but you can graphically build queries if you don't want to parse and concatenate.

If this is going to be a big, repetitive task, I would look at writing a Perl script to parse a query and rewrite it as needed.  This would require some inside knowledge.  It isn't clear what you want to do regarding updating the values so you'd have to design your solution around that.  More likely you would want to write a functional API (a UDF) to do what you want, and then write calls to that, probably not in a config file directly (since it is not clear you can trust that) but through an interface.

Comment: The page doesn't exist and besides your answer is plain theory and no concrete answer or even a hint of it.